# Parallax Scrolling Road-2D

Tags: cocos2d-x, parallax-scrolling

I'm working on a racing game which will have a top view from the back camera. The image below displays a similar example. I am confused about how to achieve the movement of the road if parallax scrolling is used. The road gets narrow as we move forward whereas it is broader closer to the camera. Should I focus on parallax scrolling to achieve this or is there some other technique to work with such games?

p.s. I'm using cocos2d-x as the gaming engine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to some similar queries..I can't add comment  there (don't have as many points)..Is it possible to achieve this with a 2d engine like cocos2dx..it seems that the perspective thing works in 3 dimensions? any more help?