# How is the "continues road" from 80's games called and done?

Tags: algorithm

i like to test the "continues road" effect from 80's racing games . i call it like this i have no idea how it really called 
the effect that a car is in front of you , and the road is Approaching to you ,
some thing that can seen in games like : 
http://www.myabandonware.com/game/turbo-1ti
http://www.myabandonware.com/game/angel-nieto-pole-500-sp-2le

where i can find example of implementing such alurithem ? c++ is prefered but dosn't have to be c++ .
​Thanks !

Comment: you mean "continuous"?

Comment: there are several ways to accomplish this.
If you want to generate a truely pseudo3d road with a map, you might be after "mode7" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_7)
The games you linked however seem to simply draw lines / textures along a curve.

Comment: Duplicates: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49626/best-technique-to-create-oldschool-fake-3d-racing-game http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62680/parallax-scrolling-road-2d?lq=1 http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22953/how-would-i-implement-an-endless-road-the-player-runs-down

Comment: Have a look here : http://www.extentofthejam.com/pseudo/ and here  http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2012/6/22/javascript_racer/